Changing SSH port does not seem to work ubuntu 24.10
Today I did a clean install of ubuntu 24.04, which I then upgraded to 24.10.
I installed wireguard, added my SSH key and then tried to change the SSH port.
By reading this article, I found out, the new way of editing the port is as follows:
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/10-custom-ssh.conf
There is added the following content (port changed for security reasons):
Port 54265
I also added the sshd config the following way:
sudo systemctl edit ssh.socket
with the following content:
[Socket]
ListenStream=
ListenStream=54265

I then used these command to restart the services:
systemctl restart ssh
systemctl restart ssh.socket

Afterwards I restarted the server. But now I was not able to login anymore:
I always get a Connection refused error.
I get the error on port 22 (as expected) but also on port 54265. I do not have any firewall enabled.
Once I revert these changes via a rescue system, I'm able to login again.
Does anyone know, if something changed from 24.04 to 24.10 regarding this and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Maybe this will help.

Yes indeed this post solves my issue. Thanks for linking it!
